# Configure shortest path calculation with specific origin/destination points

Tags: road, path

I would like to calculate the shortest path from a point to another following a network. I'm currently using QNEAT3 for that purpose, but I can either calculate one path from two specific points or a full OD matrix (so based on all unique origin/destination combinations). What I'm trying to do is set specific OD couples (for example by first calculating a distance matrix with the 5 closest points) then calculate the distance between those combinations (and not all combinations, it is much too heavy for my computer).

Does anyone know how to handle this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to GIS.SE, Could you please specify the problem. Do you have troubles with running the algorithms or do you want to perform some other special kind of analysis using distance matrices?

Comment: Hello root676! The algorithms work great. What I'm trying to do is specify combinations of origin/destination points to avoid the calculation of a whole distance matrice (too heavy). So for example:

origin   destination
1          A
2          B

I would like to get the distance from 1 to A and 2 to B (and not 1B and 2A on top of that)

Comment: You can achieve this easily by selecting the respective points in the origin or desination layer (eg. filter the layer) and run the analysis just for this smaller number of points.

Comment: Yes you're right! But I'm trying to automate the process and cannot afford to edit the layer everytime by hand :/

Comment: But if you have to automate the process, wouldn't it be worth to compute the whole OD-Matrix once (maybe overnight) and then just select the pairs that you need in other analyses.

Comment: It takes 2 minutes to calculate one point (it has roughly 3000 potential destinations), and I need at least 20.000 points! I'll subdivide the area I think, and edit the automation for each one. Thank you for your time!! :)